# How to use <Label>k__BackingField: "Aachi" in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

How to use this `<Label>k__BackingField: "Aachi"` type of data value in ionic?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZMzQ.png)

I am getting this response in the ionic rest API response. API made in ASP .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.

```ts
export interface YourInterface {
  "<Label>k__BackingField": string;
}
```

```ts
let value: YourInterface = { '<Label>k__BackingField': 'Aachi' };
console.log(value['<Label>k__BackingField']);  // Outputs 'Aachi'
```

However, I would recommand renaming/mapping the properties so you can access them with `.` instead of `[]`. For example, you can have an `interface` for your raw API response, another `interface` with 'valid' property names, and a `function` that converts one to the other, and/or vice versa if needed.